# Error when initializing Microsoft Excel interop (64-bit)

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I have a website using asp.net with Excel 2010 Interop 64-bit (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll).

I deployed code to the Windows Server 64 bit.

By using command:

```
xelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

I see there is no error on this own server.
But from the other computer (same domain), sometimes (not always), I got the error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000401A): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a.
```

How could I fix this issue?

By install the Office 2010 64-bit to server 64-bit, I cannot see the Excel in DCOM config.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if your site working as x64 bit process? Also check your IIS process. Note that your app can work under 32bit process on 64bit system, in that case x64bit interop will not work corectly.

Comment: hi Lukasz Makowej, I will try to build as your suggest. Thanks for help.

Comment: Also you can try x32bit interop together with x32bit Office ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the folowing:

1. Is Microsoft Office Installed on the server? If not, you may install the MS Office and this feature should be working.
2. If you do not want to install the MS Office, you can use a similar tool, which is ClosedXML - [1](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

I recommend to replace the Interop Excel with the ClosedXML.

Comment: thanks your share. 
1. as I said, I installed office 64-bit to server.
2. With my project, it's hard to change to another tool, a lot of code must be change. It takes months.

Answer (score 0):

That error code occurs due to security issues like **insufficient privelage** or **due to incorrect username, password**.